# Size of element depending on size of the QListView

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, qlistview

I developing a program that draws in elements of the list (QListView).
How do I set the size of an element depending on the size of the QListView?
I write implementation of the sizeHint in the delegate, but where to get the size of the instance QListView I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
QSize SpinBoxDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt(option);

    qDebug("W = %d\n", opt.widget->width());
    qDebug("H = %d\n", opt.widget->height());
    return QSize(100, 100);
}
```